# jquery, write a function to get both new and old window.width

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i write a function that detects and caches the start and the end of a window.width resize

the width in the the .resize(funciton{}) changes instantly when resizing, but I'm after the differences between the old and new size every time it resizes.

update---

I Need to catch the diffeence so that I can do a width: '+=diff' to an element

Comment: Gotta be a small jQuery plugin out there that will do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version will update the last window size after 500 milliseconds ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/64mh2/)). And yes, some browsers update the window width only after the resize has stopped, others will actively update while you drag the window.

```
var throttle,
    win = $(window),
    cur_width = win.width(),
    old_width = cur_width,
    diff = 0;

win.resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(throttle);
    cur_width = win.width();
    throttle = setTimeout(function() {
        diff = cur_width - old_width;
        old_width = cur_width;
    }, 500);
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Thanks, but the timeout thing is rather buggy, but I suppose it only works that way with the timeout method. So the best option for me is actually to write a destroy function and rebuild on window resize.